# Android, Custom DialogFragment compatible with Android OS api level 8+

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I need to create a custom dialog fragment that works with all Android api 8 and above but I'm stuck.
My understanding is that I need to use the support library, fair enough but the activity that the dialog will be used in needs to be descended from RoboActivity and according to what I have read here http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html I would need to descend the activity from FragmentActivity which, as Java doesn't have multiple inheritance I'm at a loss as to what to do.
Not using RoboActivity is NOT an option.

So how do I go about creating a custom dialog with it's own layout that is compatible with api 8 and above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `RoboFragmentActivity` instead:-)

Comment: Sadly According to http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/UpgradingTo20 - RoboGuice 2 is not production ready

Comment: You probably might consider using AndroidAnnotations http://androidannotations.org/